# Selector to method inside singleton

Tags: swift, methods, singleton

This sounds like a stupid question, but I have been trying to find a solution for hours now, and I still don't know what to do. I am using Swift 3.0, and I am having an issue calling a method inside a singleton class from a selector inside another class. My singleton class is as follows:

```
class Singleton : NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private override init() {} // defeats instantiation

    func myAction() {
        // do something useful...
    }

}
```

Then, here is the class from which I am calling the method contained in the Singleton:

```
class StatusBarPresenter {

    func addItemsToMenu(menu: NSMenu) {
        ...
        menu.insertItem(withTitle: "Disconnect this network",
                        action: #selector(Singleton.sharedInstance.myAction),
                        keyEquivalent: "D", at: 4)
        ...
    }

}
```

Xcode doesn't complain about the code... it compiles without any errors or warnings, but the selector doesn't work. The `UIMenuItem` that I add to the menu is disabled, which means that the selector is not working. If the selector instead calls a method inside the class, everything works fine just as usual. This is a screenshot of what I am getting:

[image: A screenshot of the error]

Comment: Where do you set the *target* for the menu item action? Compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970202/1187415.

Comment: I totally forgot about it... thanks! Will add an answer. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin R. for pointing out that in my code I was not setting an explicit target for the UIMenuItem, leading to it being `nil` and ultimately `self`.
The following line added to the `addItemsToMenu` function after the call to `insertItem` solves the problem:

```
menu.item(at: 4)?.target = Singleton.sharedInstance
```